# C++ audio mixing

Tags: c++, c, audio

I want to be able to combine multiple tracks of audio into one file but have no idea what to do. I need to be able to do the following:

- I need to have multiple tracks playing simultaneously, and need to be alter the volume of each track at various points,
- I need some tracks to start at different time,
- And I need to be able to write the result to file.

I'm not sure what library to use for this, if anyone has a suggestion that would be helpful.

Comment: Punch "C++ audio library" into your favorite search engine.

Comment: http://www.un4seen.com/ - Bass ||
http://www.fmod.org/ - fmod

Comment: Depending on how low-level you want to go, you can do this yourself using, e.g. `libvorbis`. Mixing audio tracks can be done by adding the values of each track's sample (per-channel) to get the final output sample value. If this value is too large, it will need to be clipped.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz of course I have looked, there are many libraries and they seem very complicated. I am asking for suggestions from programmers who have used such a library before, not just which library has the highest PageRank.

Comment: I always write this sort of thing from scratch as it's not that complex and learning a new interface is usually more complex than just hamming out a hundred lines of code. f you don't posses the knowledge to do this from scratch, your best bet is probably libSox. It does what you are asking plus a bit more, but not so much that you'll feel overwhelmed.

Comment: @BjornRoche do you know how to use libSox with Visual Studio? I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: No, but if you have specific questions or problems, you should create a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Nobody has answered this question, so I'll post what I ended up doing. I tried using libffmpeg first, but it was far too confusing to get to work. So instead I used [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) which is available under the LGPL. It's extremely simple, but that means there's nothing messy to fool around with. The only problem is that it can't use the MP3 format, so I'll just programmatically call ffmpeg.exe and convert MP3 files to FLAC and load those. It's not perfect but it will do.

Comment: Hi, @rlbond, I'm also in the same use case as of yours. Can you please explain me what functions did you use to mix two audio file?